# ChartJS Control Doughnut Chart Padding/Size

Tags: reactjs

I am having a hell of a time controlling the size and placement of this chart.  It seems to have a large amount of padding auto-applied.  I've looked up many people complaining out this, but none of their solutions seem to work for me.  I want it to stay contained the same vertical space that the rest of the row it is in.  Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

This is the code I have currently:

```
<Row>
          <Col className="mx-auto text-dark text-md-left">
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <img className="profilepics mb-3" src={photo} alt={teamMemberName} />
                <p>
                  <strong>Date of Hire:</strong> {hiredate}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Birthday:</strong> {birthday}
                </p>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Doughnut
                  data={{
                    labels: [
                      'Billable Hours',
                      'Non-Billable Hours'
                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                      label: 'Billable Percentage',
                      radius: "50%",
                      innerRadius: "75",
                      data: [renderBillableHours, (renderTotalHours - renderBillableHours)],
                      backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(10, 120, 10)',
                        'rgb(190, 10, 10)',
                      ],
                      hoverOffset: 4
                    }]
                  }}
                  options={{
                    maintainAspectRation: false,
                    layout: {
                      autoPadding: false,
                    },
                    plugins: {
                      legend: {
                        display: false
                      }
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
            <Col className="mx-auto text-dark text-md-right">
              <h3 className="display-4">Hello, {teamMemberName}!</h3>
              <h5 className="pt-3">
                Current Billable Amount: $
                {renderBillableAmount.toLocaleString("en", {
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}{" "}
              </h5>
              <p>
                Billable Goal: ${goal.toLocaleString()} | Difference: $
                {(renderDifference).toLocaleString("en", {
                  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                })}
              </p>
            </Col>
          </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html) indicate you should be able to control padding in options:

```
const options = {
    plugins: {
        layout: {
            autoPadding: false,
            padding: 0,
        }
    }
}
...
<Doughnut data={data} options={options} />
```

However, I found that ineffective in this case. Setting a negative top margin (`margin-top: -0.5rem;` in my case) counteracted the excessive padding. You may consider doing that.